# chromecast "failed to start application: no application is running" after called startSession()

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm testing playing online video using chromecast.
After `onRouteSelected()`, I create the ApplicationSession and attach a MediaProtocalMessageStream;

Then I called `mSession.startSession();` with no APP_ID, so I assume the build-in app inside chromecast play the video for me. This code works perfect and I can play online mp4 videos without writing my own receiver.

But, When I try to leave the video play app, I can't go back anymore, there is always an error message comes from `onSessionStartFailed()` which says

> StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: no
>   application is running

I don't remember how the first time I got into the video play app, which I don't leave for few day.

But I do know how I leave it, Here is what I did before I can never startSession again:

1. open Youtube app, get a deviced connected
2. play some youtube videos
3. disconnected from a chormecast, then the chromecast return to the starting page

So, doesn't anybody know what's going on here? How to open the build-in video app again?

By the way, My chromecast get a system update just after I return to the starting page, I don't know if google update something cause startSession() fail.

Below is the code I startSession and attach a mediaStream.

```
mSession = new ApplicationSession(mCastContext, mSelectedDevice);
ApplicationSession.Listener listener = new ApplicationSession.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata) {
        mChannel = mSession.getChannel();
        mStream = new MediaProtocolMessageStream();
        mChannel.attachMessageStream(mStream);
        if (mStream.getPlayerState() == null) {
            ContentMetadata metaData = new ContentMetadata();
            metaData.setTitle("Test Video");
            String url = "http://www.auby.no/files/video_tests/h264_720p_hp_5.1_6mbps_ac3_planet.mp4";
            try {
                mCommand = mStream.loadMedia(url, metaData, true);
                mCommand.setListener(new MediaProtocolCommand.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(MediaProtocolCommand arg0) {
                        onSetVolume(0.5);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(MediaProtocolCommand arg0) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartFailed(SessionError error) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Session Started failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnded(SessionError error) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Session Started end");
    }
};
mSession.setListener(listener);
try {
    mSession.startSession();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use your own app id and own receiver. Google's default receiver doesn't play video streams anymore (it used to). It only handles Chrome tab mirroring now.

Comment: it seems like startSession() with no arguments just create session with the app currently running on the Chromecast device, it can't start new application anymore.